# Rake db:create causes segmentation fault on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault, rake, ubuntu-18.04

I am setting up a rails application on `Ubuntu 18.04`. My ruby version is `2.1.4`. Postgres version is `(PostgreSQL) 10.10`.

I installed gems using rails `Gemfile`.

Following is the snippet of error that I got while executing `rake db:create`.

```
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/puma-2.9.2/lib/puma/puma_http11.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0036 p:-11855247756540 s:0130 e:000129 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0035 p:---- s:0128 e:000127 CFUNC  :require
```

> This error occurs for any `rake` command.

Can anyone provide a solution/fix for this?

Comment: Can you try another Ruby version? Ruby 2.1.9 is the newest of the 2.1 series, or 2.5.7 which is the latest before 2.6..try to look for the latest version in the series. It will have the most patches for errors like this.

Comment: Btw. this could also be a problem in your Puma installation. You might want to rebuild the Puma gem, or try another version of it, because the error was in the Puma library `puma_http11.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Casper in comment to the question, the problem got solved by installing a newer version of puma server. I installed puma version *3.8.2*. With that `puma -v` gives proper output. also `rake db:create` works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run these commands on your project terminal:

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
gem install bundler
```

and at the end run:

```
bundle install
```

In general it will rebuild all project gems.

Comment: Execution of above command gives an error `gem "test-unit" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`. Should I remove default gems also ?

Comment: ok i followed above instructions (including deletion of default gems). still getting the same error. :( the problem is with puma. `puma -v` causes segmentation fault.